# Python logging message redirection and filtering

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7

I am looking to extend a single-user console application to allow access to multiple users. The main purpose is for the user to see status of the system and issue single commands.

All logging is performed by python's [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), which works great as the single user can specify the logging level he is interested in seeing in his console.

However, when it comes to allowing multiple users, I need to abstract from simple output of log messages to the console. My question then is, what would be the best way to redirect the output of the logging module to another location? Also, how can I distinguish log level of the individual messages in order to show varying verbosity different users? I guess I could just parse the out and the the DEBUG/INFO prefix but, surely, there has to be a better way to "tag" individual messages.

More details:

- at this moment, user views messages on local console
- in future, there will be more clients connected via web-based terminal emulations with AJAX updating (hence the need for more control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an architectural question.

If I understand your requirements properly, what you are looking for is something like this,

- You have a Python based system with one or more standard Python loggers writing to text file(s).
- You need to allow several users to access this logging data in real time, using a variety of filtering techniques to control what they access.
- Based on what they find from analysing this information, they may need to issues commands to the system to modify it's behaviour.

Given this set of requirements, I would suggest the following approach.

- Create a centralized database to store your log records.
- Populate the database using the standard Python logger and a custom logging handler that communicates directly from your logger to the database.
- Develop a server based application that mediates between the web based clients and the database.
- Use a message queue between your server logging manager and the original system to provide a transport mechanism for commands from your users to the system.

There many packages and tools that can be used to realize this scenario but I will assume that you want a primarily Python based solution and make a number of concrete suggestions.

- Use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) as your database.
- Use [MongoLog](http://github.com/puentesarrin/mongodb-log/) as the logging handler to interface between your original system and the MongoDB database.
- Develop your server application in Python using Twisted as your core framework.
- Use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) as your message queue between your logging manager and your original system.

If you are prepared to consider using non-Python based solutions I would suggest using [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) (a Javascript based environment) to develop both the web client environment and the logging manager.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I am already using Twisted to handle the threading/requests so I will explore more that way. Also, my question was also if there was a way to "subscribe" to logging level and get the information.. but I think I will need to develop that myself. I think I will use a simple in-memory solution compared to a database as I am not interested in much scrollback/history on the clients

Comment: You might want to consider [Redis](http://redis.io/) for a memory based solution with disk backup.